# Will doing a restore with Dell Backup and Recovery re-partition my Hard Disk to Factory State?

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron

I'm thinking of using the Dell Backup and Recovery Software to restore my Laptop to factory settings.

Thing is, when I got the laptop, it had only a C and D drive. I've created 2 more drives and stored all my data there.

If I use Dell Backup and Recovery, to restore things to the way when it arrived, will it delete these new drives I've create and delete all data on my Hard Disk, or will it restore only to the C: drive and leave data on the other drives intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dell Recovery Software will repartition your ENTIRE disk to the way it arrived from the factory.

Assuming your 2 extra disks are on the same drive, they will be deleted the C/D partitioning scheme will be restored.

You might want to look at using EASUS ToDo Backup to make images of these partitions and plan on restoring them later once you get your partitioning fixed after restore.

If your using Windows 8, and have a bunch of bloat that makes you want to reimage your machine, you might want to look at "Refresh" which will reinstall Windows 8 without having to format.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Boy, am I glad I asked...